# How to troubleshoot decryption issues for Rails credentials.yml.enc after regenerating master key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, runtime-error, credentials

Description:

I am facing challenges decrypting the config/credentials.yml.enc file in my Ruby on Rails application after successfully regenerating the config/master.key. Despite following the standard procedure for key regeneration, the decryption process consistently fails.
Steps Taken:

```
1. Executed the following commands in the terminal:
   bashCopy code




rm config/master.key
   EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit

   The config/master.key was successfully regenerated, and I securely saved the key.
2. Attempted to decrypt the config/credentials.yml.enc file using the new master key:
   bashCopy code




EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

Received the error message:

```
Couldn't decrypt config/credentials.yml.enc. Perhaps you passed the wrong key?
```

Additional Information:

```
• Verified that the contents of config/master.key match the key used during regeneration.

• Manual decryption attempts using rails encrypted:edit also resulted in failures.
```

How can I effectively troubleshoot and resolve the decryption issue for the config/credentials.yml.enc file after regenerating the master key? Are there any specific steps, considerations, or common pitfalls that I might be overlooking?

I am seeking guidance and insights from the community to help me address this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the credentials.yml.enc file and recreated it:

```
rm config/credentials.yml.enc
EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

After recreating the file, the decryption issue was successfully resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).